# REST API URI Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-table-storage

Here is the following code to retrieve data from Azure table storage (AzureTableHelper.cs) and display in JSON format.

Could you please tell me the correct format of the URI for `pid`, `sid`, and `top` for the below code?

As suggested,I  tried as http://localhost:51904/api/tracks/ which gives me empty results.Could someone please help me for writing this URL?

Many Thaks in advance

ValuesController.cs

```
using AzureREST.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace AzureREST.Controllers
{
    public class TracksController : ApiController
    {
        AzService AzService = new AzService();

        private CloudTable Wndashboard;

        public TracksController()
        {
            Wndashboard = AzService.azManager.Wndashboard;
        }

        // GET api/values        
        public IEnumerable<AzManager.Rc522Entity> Get()
        {
            string pid = "";
            string sid = "";
            int rows = 10;

            var nvc = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(this.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString);

            IList<AzManager.Rc522Entity> rs = new List<AzManager.Rc522Entity>();

            foreach (var item in nvc.AllKeys)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (item.Contains("pid"))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nvc[item]))
                        {
                            pid = nvc[item];

                            TableQuery<AzManager.Rc522Entity> query = new TableQuery<AzManager.Rc522Entity>()
                                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ProductionOrder", QueryComparisons.Equal, pid));

                            var retrieved = Wndashboard.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

                            if(retrieved.Result.Count()>0)
                                rs.Add(retrieved.Result.Results[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item.Contains("sid"))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pid))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nvc[item]))
                            {
                                sid = nvc[item];
                                TableQuery<AzManager.Rc522Entity> query = new TableQuery<AzManager.Rc522Entity>()
                                    .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("SerialNumber", QueryComparisons.Equal, sid));

                                var retrieved = Wndashboard.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

                                if (retrieved.Result.Count() > 0)
                                    rs.Add(retrieved.Result.Results[0]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item.Contains("top"))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nvc[item]))
                        {
                            rows = Convert.ToInt32(nvc[item]);

                            TableQuery<AzManager.Rc522Entity> query = new TableQuery<AzManager.Rc522Entity>();                                

                            var retrieved = Wndashboard.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
                            rs = retrieved.Result.Results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).Take(rows).ToList();                             
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return rs;
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AzureREST
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AzureREST
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```html
//HomeCOntroller.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AzureREST.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

[![

```html
//Azure TableHelper.cs

using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace AzureREST.Models
{
    public class AzManager
    {
        private class TableManager
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
            CloudTableClient tableClient;

            public TableManager(string connectionString)
            {
                storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
                tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            }

            public CloudTable tableById(string id)
            {
                CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(id);
                table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                return table;
            }
        }

        public class Rc522Entity:TableEntity
        {
            public Rc522Entity(string productionOrder, string serialNumber)
            {
                this.PartitionKey = productionOrder;
                this.RowKey = serialNumber;
            }
            public Rc522Entity()
            {
            }

            //public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
            //public string RowKey { get; set; }
           
           
            public string ProductionOrder { get; set; }
            public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
           
        }

        private TableManager tableManager;
        public CloudTable Wndashboard;

        public AzManager(string connectionString)
        {
            tableManager = new TableManager(connectionString);
            Wndashboard = tableManager.tableById("Wndashboard");
        }
    }

    public class AzService
    {   
        static string storageAccount = "";
        
        static string skey = "";
        static string host = @"https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/";
        static string tableName = "Wndashboard";
        static string resource = string.Format(@"{0}", tableName);
        static string uri = host + resource;

        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(storageAccount, skey), true);

        public AzManager azManager = null;

        public AzService()
        {
            azManager = new AzManager("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="+ storageAccount + ";AccountKey="+skey+";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a question related to Azure Storage. Thanks Camilo for the editing!

Answer (score 0):

> As suggested,I tried as http://localhost:51904/api/tracks/ which gives me empty results

As the query string is null, so you get the empty result in your code. In your case, the pid, sid and top is the url query string. 
The format should be following:

```
http://localhost:51904/api/tracks?pid=ProductionOrder&sid=SerialNumber&top=interNumber
```

You also could get more information about query string from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

> Web frameworks may provide methods for parsing multiple parameters in the query string, separated by some delimiter. In the example URL below, multiple query parameters are separated by the ampersand, '**&**':
>
> http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple

Test Result:

[image]

Test Azure Table data

[image]